# ¿Cómo funciona el reloj en Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game

tengo una duda y es que no se como funciona el modo `pygame.time.Clock()`.

Te explico, necesito modelar una especie de mortero que dispare un proyectil y que este caiga en función de propiedades físicas al suelo, y para eso el usuario debe dar click en la tecla `Space` y con eso debería dispararse el proyectil, para ello necesito medir el tiempo para calcular la posición del proyectil en todo momento, pero no sé como funciona el medidor de tiempo por lo tanto no me dan los resultados. Si alguien me podría ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.
Puedo mandar mi código si es que es necesario.

Comment: Quizá leer la documentación oficial de Pygame te sea util para entender como funciona: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock

Comment: Con `pygame.time.get_ticks()` puedes obtener la cantidad de milisegundos desde que arrancó el juego. También puedes simplemente usar `Clock.tick(30)` por ejemplo, al final de cada draw, para solicitar 30fps, y si la máquina es lo suficientemente rápida, pygame insertará tiempos de espera necesarios entre cada ciclo de redibujado, para que efectivamente se pinte un frame cada 1/30 de segundo. Así que puedes suponer que han pasado 1/30 segundos entre cada invocación de tu rutina draw..